# TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__' when using reportLab

Tags: python, python-2.7, charts, reportlab

I know that there are loads of questions with the same name, but I couldn't find a question with the same point of problem.
I am using reportLab for creating a chart, and want to save a drawing to the file, but get the error stated above.
Here is what I have:

```
from reportlab.graphics.shapes import Drawing
from reportlab.graphics.charts.barcharts import VerticalBarChart
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF

class Charts:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = Drawing(300, 200)


    def drawChart(self, list1, list2):
        chart = VerticalBarChart()
        chart.width = 260
        chart.height = 160
        chart.x = 20
        chart.y = 20
        chart.data = list2
        chart.categoryAxis.categoryNames = list1
        chart.valueAxis.valueMin = 0
        self.d.add(chart)
        renderPDF.drawToFile(self.d, 'example1.pdf', 'My First Drawing')
```

and the error statement is quite long, so this is the end of it:

```
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/graphics/charts/axes.py", line 49, in _findMinMaxValue
if isinstance(V[0][0],_SequenceTypes):
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the types of `list1` and `list2`.

Comment: list2 is list of floats, list1 is list of strings

Comment: ooh, I found it. list2 should have been a list of lists of floats. It works now =)